# Acessing php variable using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        <?php 
        echo 'var timeLeft = 12796;'; 
        ?>;     

        console.log(timeLeft);  
    });
</script>
```

How is jquery acessing the php variable because to create a php variable we use $ and here it is using var?

Now how can i correct the below code because its showing me error in the console?

`<script> 
var currentDate= <?php echo 'strtotime("now")' ; ?>; 
console.log(currentDate); 
</script>`

Here i am using strtotime function instead of simple echoing a numbe

Comment: that `var` in the string you echo doesn't give you any clue ? there's nothing called php and jquery. there's only html and javascript.

Comment: If you are seeing this in your browser, then you are asking the wrong question. The php should have been processed before you see it in your browser, so the question is why has the php not been processed. jquery has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the side is being processed through PHP (on the server) you can just use an `echo`

```
<pre>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){        

         var myOrder = <?php echo json_encode($myVariable); ?>;
         console.log(myOrder);
    });
</script>
```

After PHP has processed the page it is just regular javascript as if you wrote it manually.

You can also imagine the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('<?php echo 'hello js' ?>');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save it as hello.php inside of your web servers document root and call it in browser.

Comment: It is giving:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  in console

Comment: The code block is taken from a page that where processed by php?

Comment: Now how can i use the below code because its showing me error in the console?<script>
var currentDate= <?php echo 'strtotime("now")' ; ?>;
console.log(currentDate);
</script> Here i am using strtotime function instead of simple echoing a number

Comment: remove the single quotes from around the strtotime call

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){       
    var timeLeft = <?php echo strtotime("now"); ?>;       

    console.log(timeLeft);  
});
</script> It is giving error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript isn't accessing the PHP, and there isn't even a PHP variable involved.

The PHP is executing, outputting some text which conforms to JavaScript syntax rules, then the browser is parsing the JavaScript.

PHP operates on (mostly) text. It doesn't care if that text is HTML, JavaScript, or something else. The output of the PHP gets sent to the browser, and it parses the text according the same rules used for anything else that comes from a web server.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this locally and this worked perfect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var timeLeft = <?php $timeLeft= '12796'; echo $timeLeft; ?>   
    alert(timeLeft);  
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var timeLeft = <?php $timeLeft=12796; echo $timeLeft; ?>   
    alert(timeLeft);  
});
```

Still don't understand `what kind issue do you have?`